# Modularization in C++

Tags: c++, modularization

I am currently working on a (very very basic) program that is a tutorial for programming( ironic given my knowledge, I know). I was instructed to modularize my code so that each unit is in its own module. I'm guessing that means adding headers? I'm working with Visual Studios, if that helps at all. I've included my code below to help my bad explanation make sense. Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int Total;
int ans;

class Question
{
private:
    string Question_Text;
    string Answer_one;
    string Answer_two;
    string Answer_three;

    int Correct_Answer;
    int Question_Score;

public:
    void setValues(string, string, string, string, int, int);
    void askQuestion();
};

int main()
{
    string username = "";
    char choice=' ';
    char c;
    int x = 4;
    int y = 5;
    int z = x + y;


    //welcome message
    cout << "Hello user, please enter your name:";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Welcome to the programming tutorial " << username << "." << endl;

    //menu selection
    while(choice != '5')
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do? (Unit 1 - Declaring Variables (1), Unit 2 - Input/ Output (2), Unit 3 - Conditionals (3), Quizzes (4) or Exit (5))";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == '1')
        {
            cout << "We will begin with defining variables. The first step to doing this is choosing which datatype your variable is.\n";
            cout << "The following are a few of the common datatypes used in programming.\n";
            cout << "Character ==> char\n";
            cout << "Integer ==> int, long, double\n";
            cout << "Boolean ==> bool\n";
            cout << endl;
            cout << "When declaring a variable, you must put its datatype before the variable name.\n";
            cout << "An example of this would be if we wanted to declare the value of x as 4.\n";
            cout << "We would write this as: \n";
            cout << "int x = 4\n";
            cout << "The program will now use the value 4 for the variable name 'x'\n";
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Now let's assume we assigned the value of 5 to the variable 'y'\n";
            cout << "If we wanted to add x and y and assign the sum to the variable 'z', we would write:\n";
            cout << "int z = x + y\n";
            cout << "Now when we use the variable 'z' in our program, it will perform the calculation given x=4 and y=5 and declare 9 as the value of the variable 'z'.\n";
            cout << "To test our code, we would write: " << endl;
            cout << "cout<<'x + y'<< z << endl; \n";
            cout << "If written correctly, it will display as: \n";
            cout << "x + y = " << z << "." << endl;

        }
        if (choice == '2')
        {
            cout << "Now that we understand the basics of declaring variables, let's discuss displaying, or output of, information to a user.\n";
            cout << "If you wanted to display a welcome message, for example, you would type:\n";
            cout << "cout << 'Welcome';\n";
            cout << "The line of code would start with 'cout' followed by two less than signs and then the message you wish to display in quotes.\n";
            cout << "Using this, you can ask the user for input.\n";
            cout << "Enter c to continue...";
            cin >> c;
            cout << "Let's say we have a program that flips a coin. You may want to ask the user how many times to flip the coin.\n";
            cout << "Assuming we previously declared this amount variable as 'int timesFlipped', we would 'cout' our question and the next line would read:\n";
            cout << "cin>> timesFlipped; \n";
            cout << "This will store the users input for the variable 'timesFlipped'\n";
            cout << "You almost always end a line of code with a semi colon." << endl;
        }
        if (choice == '3')
        {
            cout << "This unit will cover conditional expressions." << endl;
        }
        if (choice == '4')
        {
            string Question_Text;
            string Answer_one;
            string Answer_two;
            string Answer_three;

            int Correct_Answer;
            int Question_Score;
            Question q1;
            Question q2;
            Question q3;


            cout << username << ", you have chosen to take a quiz." << endl << endl;
            int ans, score = 0;
            cout << "Unit One Quiz - Variables " << endl << endl;

            q1.setValues("How would you declare the value of 'x' as 12? ",
                "x=12()",
                "x==12()",
                "x=12;()",
                3,
                1);
            q2.setValues("What do you need to put before a variable when declaring it?",
                "a name()",
                "a value()",
                "a datatype()",
                3,
                1);
            q3.setValues("Which data type would you use for a number that includes a decimal value?",
                "int()",
                "double()",
                "float()",
                2,
                1);

            q1.askQuestion();
            q2.askQuestion();
            q3.askQuestion();

            cout << "Your score out of a possible 3 is " << Total << endl;

        }
        if (choice == 'E')
        {
            cout << "Have a good day!";
            break;
        }
    }


    system("pause");
}

void Question::setValues(string q, string a1, string a2, string a3, int ca, int pa)
{

    Question_Text = q;
    Answer_one = a1;
    Answer_two = a2;
    Answer_three = a3;
    Correct_Answer = ca;
    Question_Score = pa;
}

void Question::askQuestion()
{

    cout << endl;
    cout << Question_Text << endl;
    cout << "1. " << Answer_one << endl;
    cout << "2. " << Answer_two << endl;
    cout << "3. " << Answer_three << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your answer: " << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    if (ans == Correct_Answer)
    {
        cout << "That is correct!" << endl;
        Total = Total + Question_Score;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that is incorrect" << endl;
        cout << "The correct answer was " << Correct_Answer << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In choice == '4' you have declared variables: `string Question_Text;   string Answer_one;   string Answer_two;
            string Answer_three;` I don't think they are used.

Comment: @drescherjm good eye! That's part of the cleanup I hadn't done yet oops! Thank you!

Comment: Tip: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables especially when you’re importing a lot of header files which may define a lot more things than they superficially appear to.

Comment: You should also nip the habit of declaring variables like `x1`, `x2`, ... in the bud rigtht now and start using container structures like `std::vector` to store *N* of something. It's also worth noting that argument names like `a1` and so on are really way too vague, that `answers` would be more appropriate here. Make it so you can understand the intent from the function's signature alone.

Comment: In addition, if you give your variables longer, more descriptive names, you lose a bit of time typing and stand to gain huge amounts of time when debugging (and in maintenance--often the real cost of software--once you're in the industry). good naming also results in self-documenting code, so you don't have to add noise to the code explaining what the code's doing. Code should explain what code is doing. That's the entire point of code: describe what the program does.

Comment: side note: A properly written operator in C++ chains. There is no need for `cout << "this\n"; cout << "that\n";` You can `cout << "this\n" << "that\n";` and even keep it spread across multiple lines for easier reading.

Comment: Fear the global variable. Anyone can change it at any time, making tracing what code does extremely hard. You can't count on a function taking inputs and simply grinding out an output when it could also set `total` to some number. This turns debugging into a game of "Who Trashed the Value of `total`?" when it should be the much easier game, "`total`Was Returned By `calc_total`, So That's Where the Error Is."

Comment: This is particularly relevant to this question because global variables set you up for the extremely nasty [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) when you're running programs that are spread across multiple files.

Comment: @user4581301  thank you! I'm not sure why, but the instructor asked us to use (most) of the variable names, I was also thinking that the were incredibly generic. I appreciate all of the info!!

Comment: Do what you need to do to keep the teacher happy and pass with good grades, but where there is leeway, err on the side of good, readable code. You'll find it's often more important than lightning fast code.

Comment: @tadman I've heard a lot of negative info about the using namespace std; but for whatever reason, my professor seems hellbent on us using it. I am just trying to get through this course with a good grade for my gpa, I realized a while ago that his methods and ideas are dated and inefficient lol. Thanks for taking the time to share!

Comment: As a nearly universal rule, any professor teaching C++ has almost zero clue what they're doing so take everything they say with a grain of salt and be extremely skeptical of any advice they give. There are exceptions to this rule, but they are sadly very rare. Do what you can to get a good grade, but don't let their advice damage your understanding of C++ too badly.

Comment: @tadman I'm trying! To make it worse, they started us in Python, for a semester, then went to C++ haha

Comment: "Modularizing your code" isn't exactly a precise term, but it generally refers to breaking things up into a lot of small pieces that each do well defined things. There are several ways of doing that, all with different trade-offs. Having small functions that each do one thing is one approach. Distributing code across multiple source files, and using headers to specify interfaces (e.g. function signatures) is another.  Practically, you may want to use multiple approaches - you want functions to be small and self contained, source files to have a small number of related/similar functions, etc

Comment: Example of Peter's point: `if (choice == '1') { huge block of code }` could be `if (choice == '1') { do_choice_1(); }`, and the `do_choice_1()` function contains the huge block of code. This will help keep the `main` function at a reasonable size that a human stands a chance of fitting in their brain and understanding. I've heard and read many metrics on how big a function should be, but the general gist is as small as possible to "Do one thing and do it well."

Comment: One other thing that no-one teaches at school: Learn to use the debugger that came with your development tools. All those kids getting As and still finding time to hit the pub after class? Probably already know to use the debuggers to help find problems. A debugger lets you run your program at your speed and watch what happens as it happens. When you see the program doing something you didn't expect, that'll probably be a bug or its aftermath. All you need to do is supply the correct expectations and the ol' Mark I eyeball.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing that means adding headers?

That's pretty much the idea.

In your case, you may want to:

- Create a header name `Question.h` that includes the declaration of class `Question`.
- Create a source file name `Question.cpp` and move the class definition there, ie all functions like `void Question::askQuestion()` etc.
- Create a test file name `test.cpp` to put your `main` function, and remember to include the `Question.h`

As you are using Visual Studio, you can create a Project in advance then add all those files before compiling/building.

Comment: How are you so sure that tutorial isn't about C++20 modules?

Comment: I'm not "so sure". It's a suggestion anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was incredibly helpful!!  For whatever reason, @einpoklum seems to be set on trolling my questions because I am new at this, apparently they need to make smart remarks to feel valid.

Comment: You're welcome. People have different opinions, take it easy.

Comment: @artm I would agree if this was the first comment he made lol.